# Trying to pivot output of SQL query

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I need to swap rows with columns and vice versa. Below is the query:

```
SELECT TypeName, value
FROM [RamCustomData]
where Ram = 1024 and TypeName in ('RamType','productionUnitID','version')
order by 2
```

Raw output:

```
TypeName            Value
RamType             XYZ
productionUnitID    ABC
version             V123
```

Expected output

```
TypeName     RamType        ProductionUnitID      Version
Value         XYZ             ABC                  V123
```

Could you please advise me on how to approach this task?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard PIVOT... We just had to include `TypeName='Value'`

Depending on your data, the `...and TypeName in ('RamType','productionUnitID','version')` is optional

**Example**

```
Select TypeName='Value'
      ,*
 From (
         Select TypeName
               ,value
          From  [RamCustomData]
          Where Ram = 1024 
            and TypeName in ('RamType','productionUnitID','version')
      ) src
 Pivot (max(Value) for TypeName in ([RamType],[productionUnitID],[version]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
TypeName    RamType productionUnitID    version
Value       XYZ     ABC                 V123
```

Comment: @SKumar Happy to help